# Computing numpy array prefix minima array

Tags: numpy

I have a 1-dimensional numpy array `A`. I would like to compute an array `B` of the same shape such that `B[k]` equals the minimum value of `A[:k+1]`. How can I do this efficiently (i.e. without for-loops)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `numpy.minimum.accumulate()`.

```
A = np.array([4, 1, 2, 3, -1, -5, 3])
B = np.minimum.accumulate(A)

print(B)
```

the result is `[ 4  1  1  1 -1 -5 -5]`.